# Jquery this parameter for selecting child not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, this

I've been trying to change image source on hover, however i can use mousehover function with class name and do this. The challenge here is i'm going to dynamically call more divs with same class name so i'm trying to achieve this using the this method. for some unknown reason i couldn't execute my below code. can anyone suggest what seems to be the problem? Pasting my code below

```
  $(".img_staff").mouseover(function() {
    alert(2);
    $(this).find('.staffimg:first-child').css("display","none");
    $(this).find('.staffimg:nth-child(2)').css("display","block");
    alert(3);
  });
```

Both the alerts are working fine just the inbetween 2 lines are not working. i want to achieve this effect like moca tucson site's contact page
https://moca-tucson.org/contact/
I'm trying to recreate the same effect using Jquery

Comment: please share your html too so that we can take a look at it

Comment: Just a thought, `alert` would mean, you loose `mouseOver`. Try `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from changing the image, the link that your provided also uses [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to bring that "image transition" effect.

Here's the similar effect with just CSS, without any javascript.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="https://moca-tucson.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ginger_Staff_Photos_001-800x800.jpg">
    <img src="https://moca-tucson.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ginger_Staff_Photos_002-800x800.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div img:last-child { opacity: 0 }
div:hover img:first-child { opacity: 0 }
div:hover img:last-child { opacity: 1 }
img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Hey Man! Thanks for your example. Yeah i found out how they work in that reference site. So actually when i use first-child or last-child the css is not working so i added a class manually to the firs and the second image and the code now works. Thanks for your help again man, your method made me find out the exact solution. Please find my below working code

        .pic_div img.img_hover{ opacity: 0;}
        .pic_div:hover img.img_normal{opacity: 0;}
        .pic_div:hover img.img_hover{opacity: 1;}

Comment: Got it, glad it worked man. Please see that in my example there are just 2 img elements in the only div, so it will work for anyone trying to find the solution to this in the future. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27vcnaug/) for you to see.